# Summing mapped values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My situation is the following: I have a table in which there are codes of working shifts i.e. :

```
John | 1 | 34 | 1 | 34 | Total: | 40    <---- 
Maria| 1 | 1  | 1 | 1  | Total: | 32    <----I need a formula for this last cell
```

Every one of this codes has hours amount set in another table.

```
Codes | Hours
1     | 8
34    | 12
```

I need to calculate the total amount of work hours based on the codes. I have found ways to map the values to the other table with INDEX and MATCH but when I try to do it for a lot of rows it just gives me the first code mapped, not an array with the mapped values.

Comment: Can you count up the number of times each code appears, then `INDEX`-`MATCH` over the amount of hours per code, then multiply one by the other?

Comment: Well I could probably, but if I add a lot of different codes won't I have to make this for every single code ?

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't you have to do that anyway? If you use dynamic ranges or tables, everything should update automatically. I can't get to a computer until tomorrow night, but if you haven't got an answer by then I'll try and create an example.

Comment: Alternatively have 3 sheets, `Sheet1` with your data, a second with your `codes` and hours, then a 3rd use as a `matrix` page replicating Sheets 1. In your Matrix page in A1 put something like `=INDEX(codes!$B:$B, MATCH(Sheet1!A1, codes!$A:$A, 0))`, then copy and paste that to cover the same range as your first sheet covers, Then when summing up values instead of `=SUM(A2:A5)` for example, use `=SUM(matrix!A2:A5)`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what will help is the following custom VBA function(see example below). Use as follows:

```
=multipleMatch(range of cells to look in, range of cells to INDEX, range of cells to MATCH)
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

```
Function multipleMatch(inputRng As Range, indexRng As Range, matchRng As Range) As Double

    On Error GoTo errhandle

    Dim runTot As Double
        runTot = 0
    Dim cll As Range
    Dim mtch As Long

    For Each cll In inputRng
        If Not IsError(cll.Value) Then
            On Error Resume Next
            mtch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(cll.Value, matchRng, 0)
            On Error GoTo errhandle
            If mtch <> 0 Then
                runTot = indexRng(mtch) + runTot
            End If
        End If
    mtch = 0
    Next cll
    multipleMatch = runTot
    Exit Function


errhandle:
    multipleMatch = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    Exit Function

End Function
```

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks. It's working like a charm. Only one question, when I apply to a row of codes its's working but when I apply it to a column of codes it gives pretty much random numbers. What can be causing this ?

Comment: Okay, there was a bug actually caused by not setting `mtch` to 0 and when there was an empty cell it added the last code to the total. I fixed my adding `mtch = 0` over the `mtch = Application....` line.

Comment: Good spot - thanks. I should have looked a bit closer, but I was in a rush. I'm glad it's helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you have upper table going to the right? 
Is there more than John in it?

If the upper table is the record of actually worked shifts, and the bottom one is the default working hours by shift code, and you plan on having more people, then i could suggest the following solution that will also re-organises your tables a little bit, and utilises Excel tables which will allow you to avoid having to maintain the formulas and ranges:

1. select your Bottom table range, press Ctrl+t which will turn it into
   a blue table.
2. Rename columns just for this example to work - you can rename after you're done with steps here.
3. your "upper" table gets transposed, having 3 columns Name, Shift Code, Hours.
4. Do the same thing with it: select range, press ctrl+t, tick "Table has Headers" in the pop-up window. Rename columns as in picture.
5. in the 1st cell of **Hours** Column of table 2 (as in picture), paste this formula and hit Enter. (Now is a good time to change column names to your preference)

   =SUMIF(Table1[Shift Code],[@[Shift Code]], Table1[Default Hours])
6. Create a pivot table of Table #2 next to it or wherever you ened it.

If you add data to tables 1 and 2, formulas will update automatically in table 2, and pivot table source. Refresh pivot table to see updated totals.

this is what it would look like.

I hope this is what you tried to achieve.

[image: exampl]
and if you want, you can put Shift Code into Columns area of pivot table as in the picture below, and have it broken down by code as well as a grandtotal:

[image: pic2]

*****P.S. Please remember to mark the most useful answer as "Answer" and vote up if other answers or comments were helpful*****

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure that's what I need. I will update my question with better tables

Comment: @Rokner i can't see how this is sustainable if dataset expands to the right and down. However, I assume there is a strong need in that format exactly, in which case you should go with other solutions

Comment: if the sequence and grid are important, you could insert an incremental count function in the table, and be able to put these codes into grid in my solution, too - fyi.

Comment: Yeah but this table won't extend. It will display the working shifts for a month which are always the same size but just with different shifts.

Comment: do i understand correctly that every month you would be manually typing shift codes into your monthly shifts table? How much variation in shift codes would you have - 1 and 34 or many more?

Comment: Many more. Around 20 maybe. And yes I will write it manually because every month every worker will have different shifts.